# The intersection of philosophy and commerce

Tags: ethics, political-philosophy

One of the things that seems the most bizarre about philosophy as discipline is its horrible record at producing an income. As people deeply knowledgable and interested in the big problems surrounding ethics, how humans ought to behave, and the meaning of life and the universe, you would think there would be a monetary value attached to that knowledge! Especially with a populace who is deeply uniformed, and does seem to be (at least tangentially) curious about the results yielded by modern disciplined philosophical discussion.

So it got me thinking. Is it possible to produce an economically viable philosophy company? What would such a company look like? And what kind of business model could it use?

Potential business models:

- Call Centers | something like a pay per minute phone line that connects you to an informed individual with the worldview of your choice. (I would pay)
- Churches | non-profit weekly secular meet-ups where those who do not follow philosophy as a discipline can sit and here a pragmatic lecture on how they ought to behave.
- Books | While the idea of individual philosophers having financial success through selling books is nothing new, the idea of a company employing teams of philosophers to produce practical ethics manuals has not happened.
- Subscription Service | Similar model as books, but as a paid subscription service online. This would have the benefit of regular updates.
- Consultancy | This already exists to an extent with corporations higher experts in ethics to improve their image after some calamity.
- Cooperative | Something of a non-profit collective of less serious but interested individuals paying to a service in which all can participate, but with a core committee of philosophers and employees keeping the system and discussion running.

What do you think? What kind of model do you feel is appropriate and feasible? Or is my whole concept seriously flawed?
 -

Comment: If you think there's no monetary value attached to philosophy you just have to look at the church, all the gurus etc. You just have to package yourself well if you want to make money as a philosopher.

Comment: Or business gurus.

Comment: While definitely an interesting concern, I'm a little worried about the way this is framed. Can you tell us a little bit more about your context and motivations? What might you be reading or studying that has made this an important concern?

Comment: @JosephWeissman 1. It doesn't makes sense to me that philosophy is not a well paying gig in modern society. 2. How can we use the myriad benefits of modern economic success for philosophy?

Comment: Neither of these strike me really as practical questions or challenges you're encountering in your study of a particular philosophical work or theory. Again I think it would be much more constructive if you could tell us a little more about the context and motivations behind the concern -- what you might be reading or studying that has made this question an urgent one for you; what you might have found out so far; what sort of answer you might be expecting; etc. I'm closing for the time being pending some clarification

Comment: I am asking for a definitive answer as to : is a philosophy company feasible? Motivation aside, thats it.

Comment: Keep in mind great questions ask for explanations about very specific problems or challenges encountered during the study of philosophy. Asking for help with your business plan is probably not an ideal way to frame your concern for this community.

Comment: I am not looking to start a business, nor am I asking for help with a business plan. Perhaps this is the wrong community for this concern. I am new to this part of the stack exchange and possibly over eager to ask one of the fundamental quandaries I have regarding philosophy. Perhaps asking about the role of philosophy is not itself a philosophy question.

Comment: Much in the same way that asking 'why server-side objective-c has not caught on in the industry' is not a good question for stackoverflow. However, if that is the nature of philosophy overflow, I would find it hard to ask a good question without assuming the answer.

Comment: Let's try to move to chat or meta to discuss this further, but very quickly: the community definitely favors questions that arise from actual problems encountered while studying philosophy.

Comment: I do sense we may be talking past one another somewhat here; please do ping me in chat or bring this up on meta if you'd like to dig a bit further into how we might better frame your concern

Comment: I will ping you in chat tomorrow. Or you can reach me on skype at 'fresheyeball'. Cheers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3813/discussion-between-fresheyeball-and-joseph-weissman)

Answer (score 3):

Your statement can be inverted: One of the things that seems the most bizarre about economy based on income as is its horrible record at producing the philosophical ideas.

In my opinion, economy based on income is something temporary, that will eventually perish, and the philosophy will stay, because it asks the most important questions about who we are and where we are going. These questions will always stay on topic.

The philosophy need not to produce income. The greatest philosophers haven't written their prominent works for profit, they asked the big questions because of these questions itself. If someone just wants money, he/she won't be the great philosopher, because great philosopher is someone who **loves wisdom**, so he/she doesn't need the financial encouragement to be philosopher.

Comment: The inversion is really interesting. I agree that philosophy will be here long after the income based economy. But in the temporary, do you see an means of changing the paradigm?

Answer (score 2):

Your core supposition is wrong, look at its historical record: Universities are a large part of any modern economy. It's where people go to pursue philosophy in its widest sense. A PhD=Doctorate in Philosophy which reveals its historical roots. Would universities have been even envisaged without the marvel that was Platos Academy? Also consider how much Science is implicated in the economy, again this is an off-shoot of understanding the world empirically - a philosophical enterprise. That Science has become an autonomous activity and splintered into vast number of self-motivated disciplines is only a reflection of the success of the enterprise.

But you are also right: Philosophers pursuing Philosophy professionally are not rich, and at least here in the UK, it has something of an image problem. The problem runs deeper, as at some universities Philosophy departments are being run down, as they are seen to have no direct short-term economic benefit.

One can argue that the business model is not appropriate to the pursuit of Philosophy, that to squeeze it in serves only to cheapen it; and that it does vastly benefit society both socially and economically in subtle and sophisticated ways; and that business is myopic in looking only to the short-term future for profits, and the short term past for placing due credit.

Comment: Hmmm... While universities are a large part of the modern economy, I would hardly consider a profession that can principally only survive inside university, and even then suffers from low demand and poor image, a record of economic  success.

Comment: Furthermore the idea the economic success cheapens something, or detracts from its value, is very odd to me, and needs to be further supported. The primary benefit would be that more people could devote more time to philosophy, as they would not need to supplement/produce their income with other activities. If you feel that having more people, having more time to devote to philosophy is not worth while and somehow a detraction, then I question your engagement to the discipline at all. Or do you feel philosophy really has no value?

Comment: One last thing. You cannot lay the success of all empirical enterprises at the feet of philosophy. Philosophy is under the empirical umbrella, not the other way around.

Comment: So you don't consider the invention of the microchip which has powered the last quarter century of explosive growth in IT in all its multifarious ramifications, and which goes back to the discovery of the electron an economic success? or to take another, how about bio-tech which traces it work back to the discovery of DNA?

Comment: Tell that to Leucipus & Democritus who in hypothesised atoms in 400BC. Or to the whole rationalist/empirical turn from mytho-poetic in Greek thought at around that time.

Comment: I don't lump all empirical disciplines together, so no.

Comment: For example : I work in the IT world, and there are people who have great IT skills and no philosophy skills what-so-ever.

Comment: So have I, but I don't think I could have invented the microchip, or come up with the quantum theory that led to it. How about your colleagues?

Comment: Faulty appeal to authority. It does nothing to show that philosophical understanding is NEEDED for science or technology.

Comment: Not when Science has become an autonomous discipline, agreed. You need to look at when it was initiated, both in early Greek science, and when it kicked off in the modern era, that is the Renaissance.

Comment: I will agree that historically philosophy has been economically successful. However it is not in modern times. I am look at ways to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Some philosophers seem to be doing a kind of "applied philosophy", some sort of service similar to psychoanalytic work. I'm not sure how it goes, but it does exist. It is known as http://www.thephilosophyclinic.com/FAQ.html, as far as I'm concerned.

This reminds me of the movie "I heart Huckabees", in which there are "existential detectives", who perform investigations to solve people's crisis.

Comment: Can you send a link?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: here ttp://www.thephilosophyclinic.com/FAQ.html